# JavaScript - Initial value to Target value within a set time

Tags: javascript

I have an integer value that I want to take from the initial value of 0 to 100 over the span of 10 seconds; However, I don't want it to start from 0 and go instantly to 100 within that time-span, I want it to climb up to that value overtime, so from 0 to 1 to 2, etc. How could this effect be achieved?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't know of this keyword and didn't know the words to search for it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: [Massive dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=count+one+by+one+every+second+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` and update the value:

```js
    let value = 0;
    
    let interval = setInterval(function () {
      if(value >= 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return 
      }        

      value++;
      
      document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = value;
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="value">0</div>
```